# Error 500 - Internal server error And Cart is not showing products with success message Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am keep receiving this error on my magento pages in frontend and back-end.

> Error 500 - Internal server error An
>   internal server error has occured!
>   Please try again later.

In front-end all the pages working fine but when I hit proceed to checkout it is showing this error and the url is `/index.php/checkout/onepage/`.

My cart is also not showing products in it but when I say add to cart. It shows an empty cart with the message that the product has been added in to cart and button to proceed to checkout or continue shopping.
[image]

What are the causes? Ho do I go about this?

Comment: check the apache error logs /var/log/apache/error.log

Comment: or from cpanel, which you are more likely to have a direct access to.

Comment: if you look at the sales_flat_quote_item ... are there any items being added there?

Comment: Hi @Daric, i got the same problem with you, i'd like to know how to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say what's going on based solely on just a 500.

Magento has this behaviour of shielding the real issue at hand to avoid exposing any vulnerabilities to end-users.
In order to find out what's going on you'd have to get the real error report.

I can think of four ways to find out what's going on:

1. Check the Magento logs, you can find these in `MAGENTO_ROOT/var/log`
2. Check the error report that has been generated for this error. I'm not 100% sure if all Magento versions generate these, they might have to be enabled somewhere. If they are being made, they will appear in `MAGENTO_ROOT/var/report`
3. Check your web server error logs if you have access to those. Usually found under `/var/log` or a directory under your account if you are on a shared hosing environment.
4. Enable error logging in your PHP configuration. Run a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see what `php.ini` your server is using, edit that file, and set `log_errors = On` and define a log path (which requires write permissions for the account that PHP runs under) with the `error_log = /path/to/php.error.log` directive.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.

The first thing to check are the file permissions.

If you have ssh access then go to your public_html folder and typre 'chmod -R ugoa+rw *' to give read/write access to every other user (including your webserver user, e.g. www-data).

This should not expose your files to others in a shared hosting environment that uses #cpanel# due to the way that #cpanel# works.

I note from your URL that you are not using re-writes, you might want to enable these too as it is generally best practice to not have the 'index.php'